# How can this click event be refactored as adviced by Resharper

Tags: c#, lambda, resharper

I want to make my click events as small as possible and I thought I went all the way by defining my click events like this :

```
myButton.Click += (s,e) => { DoSomething(); } ;
mySecondButton.Click += (s,e) => { this.Close(); } ;
```

But resharper keeps bugging me by telling me

> Use lamba expression

Isn't it what I just did?  How can this be minimized even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are using is *lambda statement* because of the curly-braces. Since you are only calling one method, `ReSharper` suggests you to remove braces and use a *lambda expression*:

```
myButton.Click += (s,e) =>  DoSomething();
```

These are different, one of them is expression lambda:

```
(parameters) => expression;
```

And other one is (the one you are using currently) statement lambda:

```
(parameters) => { statement(s); };
```

You can see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details

Comment: Sorry I forgot a line. It's says the same even with the anonymous method.

Comment: Oh actually it is exactly the same -_- thanks much ! :P